# $T:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ not injective nor surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there a linear application  $T:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ which is not injective nor surjective ? same question for linear applications from $\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^2}$.

**Edit:**

I am looking for nontrivial applications of the form $T(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy,dx+ey)$. Maybe even better if we can find a characterization of such applications in term of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

Comment: @Shanye2020 I tried something like $T(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy,dx+ey)$ but couldn't find the right coefficients, $a,b,c,d,e,f$ except $a,b \dots=0$. I forgot to add that I am looking for nontrivial applications, is it ok if I modify the question ?

Comment: @user431768 Notice that it is enough to ask for not injective functions, because there is no surjective linear function in this context: if $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear transformation between the vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then [$\dim V=\dim{\ker{T}}+\dim{\operatorname{im}T}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: We have an academic case of cancel culture. There is nothing wrong with the question. ?One can get some short proofs using rank-nullity theorem. Yet people decided to go ahead and close it. In fact, someone even provided answer. hostility even in defining "bad", "off-topic " etc questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: In standard bases, take $P(e_1,2_2)=e_2$ followed by $i:\mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ given by $(e_2) \mapsto e_2$ which  or even $T(x)=0 \in \mathbb R^3$ for all $x \in \mathbb R ^2$.

For a large class of such examples, given a proper subspace $\mathbb R^k \subset \mathbb R^n$, we can always take $e_1,\dots, e_k$ as a basis for $\mathbb R^k$ (in standard co-ordinates) and form the projection $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^k$ given by $(e_1, \dots,e_n) \mapsto (e_1, \dots e_k)$.

As before, take $P:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^k$ and let $\alpha:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^m$ (for $m>n$) be any linear transformation (take your choice of coefficients.) Then $\alpha \circ P$ will be neither surjective nor injective.

Here is an explicit example: take the space $Span\{(1,1)\}$. We can project onto it like so: $(1,0) \mapsto (1,1)$ and $(0,1) \mapsto (1,1)$ giving the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$. Here, $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x+y)$. To be more correct, $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,x+y,0)$ after inclusion into $\mathbb R^3$.

To see that it is not surjective, notice that $P(x,y)=(1,2,3)$ has not solution. To see that it is noninjective notice that any vector $(x,-x)$ is in the kernel.

Comment: I was just looking for something nontrivial like $T(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy,dx+ey)$

Comment: I gave you a very large class of examples. If you just want some strange collection of coefficients, follow the projection with any linear transformation you like, and this is guaranteed to be both noninjective and non-surjective.

Comment: Thanks!, it makes sense now, I just get it when you completed the vector by zero. It was a misunderstanding about notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both. Take the zero map; $T(x)=0$ for any $x$. Also note, a linear map on finite dimensional vector spaces is injective if and only if it is surjective (assuming domain and range have the same dimension).

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba yes.